# How to use OIDC with a JSP + Spring MVC based application

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, saml, openid-connect, keycloak

We have a bunch of application on which we are using SAML with Keycloak as our identity provider. This set up helps us achieve SSO within our 15 odd application. Almost all these applications are JSP+Spring WebFlow + Spring MVC so we are using SAML and one of your application is Angular+REST so we are using OIDC with Keycloak.

Irrespective of the protocol and technology we are able to achieve seamless SSO between these applications as our identity provider is same.

Today we got a new update that for our application modernization push we will have to pass our JWT token to all crucial internal back-end services we are using as in this way our back-end calls can also do their own authorization and authentication.

For the application where I am using OIDC I can always pass JWT as I have it always once the user logs in. But as for SAML enabled application I do not have it as of now.

Here I can think of one solution i.e to migrate all the 14 applications from SAML to OIDC but as the applications are JSP+Spring Web FLow + Spring MVC based I am not sure if that is possible. Even if it possible, I think it will be a considerable overhead to migrate all the apps as that will require enough testing for any regression.

If you think that OIDC can work with a JSP and Spring MVC/WebFlow based app then can you share some more insights into it as in OIDC all session management is done at the client side but in case of Spring MVC/WebFlow all the session is maintained at the server side.

Can someone here suggest me some better way of doing this. There is no way to escape from this requirement of passing JWT's to back-end calls so I really need something for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you could in some way integrate both protocols in a service, but definitely the way to go here is to migrate to OIDC, from my point of view.

At Keycloak side, it should require only changing the type of the client from SAML to OIDC. In your applications you might need to do more configuration, but if you're using the [Spring Security SAML Extension](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/) it shouldn't be that difficult, as you could migrate to the [Keycloak Adapter](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_security_adapter), which works at the top of Spring Security too.

You obviously don't need to migrate all the applications at once, as you can keep different client types being compatible in the meanwhile.

Comment: SAML does work fine with JSP and Spring MVC based app but my major concern was can we make OIDC work with JSP based app as ideally in OIDC all your session management is done at client side in the JS layer but in JSP all the session management is done at the server side.

Comment: It depends on what you call `session management`.. The Spring Security Keycloak adapter binds the session token in the client with the access token info in the server (which is almost the same way you're using it in SAML). Then the adapter takes care of refreshing the tokens, so it makes the server `handle` the session in some way, that's true. If you want the web browsers manage the access token, you should go with the JS adapter, but that might involve more work for you, even switching the view technology to a more 'javascriptish' one.. Really a bunch more of work!

Comment: I think now I get it, Basically as we have Keycloak SAML adapters installed on our JBoss we will now install Keycloak OIDC adapter. Here the new OIDC JBoss adapter will handle all the token management and thus will be bound by the server. Yes I think changing the FE tech would not be a viable option as that would lead to huge amount of re write. Thanks @xtreme-biker for your help. Really appreciate.